# Craft CMS 3 storage doesn't exist or isn't writable by PHP

Tags: craft3

I am going to do an internship in February where they work with Craft CMS and thus I am going to learn it at home with XAMPP ( localhost). However I've installed it and now it will simply give me the following error:

> D:\xampp\htdocs/storage doesn't exist or isn't writable by PHP. Please fix that.

I have tried to remove the "read-only ". Everything is on full control through the security tab. I got no clue how to "allow" this to write.

Answer (score 1):

I'm on Windows 10, so if you're on another version of Windows, things might be slightly different.

If you right click on that "storage" folder, go to Properties, click the "Security" tab, click "Edit", click "Add", type "Everyone", then click "Check Names" so it finds the user (an underline will show up under it), click "OK", make sure "Everyone" is selected, then check the "Full control" checkbox under permissions, click "OK", then "OK" to close the final modal, that will give everyone access to write to that folder (including PHP/Craft).

Obviously, don't do this on production, but since you're on a local box you should be fine.